# How to sort a list of the most frequently repeated words through Hadoop mapreduce WordCount?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Hi I am a newbie to hadoop mapreduce.

Could anyone of you help me to modify the below posted code to display the desired output?

I've a given input file as

**Input**: `Hi my name is John.Im doing my engineering.My parents stay at California`

I get the output as

```
Hi    1
my   3
name  1
is    1
is 1
John 1
doing  1
engineering 1
parents  1
stay  1
at  1
California   1
```

But I **want the output to be sorted** as

```
 my   3
 Hi   1 
 etc.....
```

then all the others to be displayed. The concept is to display the words that are repeated maximum times should be sorted and displayed first.

I'm running this job on a Single node. And I'm running this job as

```
        $ hadoop jar job.jar input output
```

And i've started

```
        $ hadoop namenode -format
        $ hadoop namenode

        $ hadoop datanode
        sbin$ ./yarn-daemon.sh start resourcemanager 
        sbin$ ./yarn-daemon.sh start resourcemanager
```

I'm running hadoop-2.0.0-cdh4.0.0

```
        package org.apache.hadoop.examples;

        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.util.StringTokenizer;
        import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
        import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

        import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
        import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
        import org.rg.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
        import oapache.hadoop.io.Text;
        import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
        import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
        import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
        import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
        import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
        import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;

        public class WordCount {
        private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(WordCount.class);

          public static class TokenizerMapper
               extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

            private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
            private Text word = new Text();

            public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
                            ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
              StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
              while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
                word.set(itr.nextToken());
                context.write(word, one);
              }
            }
          }

          public static class IntSumReducer
               extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
            private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

            public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
                               Context context
                               ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
              int sum = 0;
              //printKeyAndValues(key, values);

              for (IntWritable val : values) {
                sum += val.get();
              LOG.info("val = " + val.get());
              }
              LOG.info("sum = " + sum + " key = " + key);
              result.set(sum);
              context.write(key, result);
              //System.err.println(String.format("[reduce] word: (%s), count: (%d)", key, result.get()));
            }


          // a little method to print debug output
            private void printKeyAndValues(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values)
            {
              StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
              for (IntWritable val : values)
              {
                sb.append(val.get() + ", ");
              }
              System.err.println(String.format("[reduce] key: (%s), value: (%s)", key, sb.toString()));
            }
          }

          public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            Configuration conf = new Configuration();
            String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
            if (otherArgs.length != 2) {
              System.err.println("Usage: wordcount <in> <out>");
              System.exit(2);
            }
            Job job = new Job(conf, "word count");
            job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
            job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
            job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
            job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
            job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
            job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
            FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[0]));
            FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[1]));

            System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
        }
        }
```

I would be great if anyone could sort this think out.

Comment: The question is on how to print the words which are being frequently used to be printed first.

Comment: I believe the question is very clear. In our usual wordcount example, the output is lexically ordered by word. All he/she wants it get the result which is ordered by count instead.

Comment: how about writing another map-reduce job which will order them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about decreasing the count each time you find a word? Starting from 0 you will have -ve count of numbers.Highest count should come first then.